# android/twitter4j question

Tags: android, twitter4j

greetings all!

i'm trying to work my way through a twitter implementation.  i've followed several tutorials and finally made progress with this implementation: [code.](http://agirardello.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/OAuthExample/src/ch/ethz/oauth/OAuth.java)

All appears well as i'm authorized through the twitter browser app and even returned back to my app/view via the callback.  this is where i'm confused... at this point, i assumed the onNewIntent() method is called and a test tweet is sent?  if so, this doesn't work for me...no error are thrown/logged.  can someone pls tell me what i'm missing?

resources used:
 - twitter4j-core-2.1.7
 - signpost-core-1.2.1.1
 - signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1
 - 2.1 SDK

Answer (score 0):

added the following to my manifest file and activity:  android:launchMode="singleInstance"

works like a charm!